# Cross platform Missing Templates after updating Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, missing-template

Cross platform Missing Templates after updating Visual studio 2017,i tried looking for a solution from Xamarin forums page in vain.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed it correctly? Check this link -> [Mobile development with .NET](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/xamarin/xamarin-dvelopment-with-vs-2017)

Comment: Yes am sure, everything was okay before updating Vs 2017 just like on the link. After updating, the Xamarin option does not exist anymore in the Tools>Options window

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Did you try reinstalling Xamarin?

Comment: @Curiosity i did re-install, everything is okay now. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some templates no longer exist in VS2017, but others it's just organized a bit differently in how you get to the specific template you want.

Example:
The Blank App and Blank XAML App templates no longer exist in VS2017. Instead, choose the "Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native)" template. A wizard pops will appear allowing you to choose a native Xamarin app or a Xamarin Forms app, as well as choosing a Shared or PCL app, as well as selecting a XAML app.

Comment: Yes i know about those changes, but the real problem is the wizards. The don't show up and project creation fails